# No Views folder is auto-generated when I create MVC controller with views, using Entity Framework in Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0

In my Asp.Net Core application, I am adding a new controller such that its relevant View folder (Course) be auto-generated under the Views folder when I click on MVC controller with views, using Entity Framework in the Add Scaffold dialog box. Under the Add Controller dialog box, I've selected Course as my Model Class and SchoolContext as my Data Context Class. When I add the controller, No Views folder is created for the CoursesController (The default name for this generated controller). I am following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro) and everything works fine for the StudentsController I've created earlier.

Any help will highly be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked on the Generate Views checkbox in the Add Scaffold dialog box after choosing my Model Class as Course and Data Context Class as SchoolContext and it works.